# How to have one public/.htaccess per stage using capistrano-ext

Tags: ruby-on-rails, .htaccess, environment-variables, capistrano

I'm using Capistrano multistage (capistrano-ext) to deploy to staging or production.

The problem is I'm using Passenger in my shared hosting and need to specify the `PassengerAppRoot` in the `public/.htaccess` file. Obviously this is different between stages.

How can I keep different "stage-versions" of this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used capistrano-ext, but I'm assuming somewhere in your Capfile you'll have the stage as a variable. Let's assume it's the variable 'stage'. Let's also assume you have the two different versions checked in somewhere in your code (public/.htaccess-{production|staging})

You could set up a task to symlink (or copy) the right file after a deploy:

```
desc 'Set up a stage-appropriate .htaccess file'
task 'update_htaccess' do
  run "ln -s #{release_path}/public/.htaccess-#{stage} #{release_path}/public/.htaccess"
end

after "deploy:update_code", "update_htaccess"
```